# How to convert a string of numbers into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string e.g. `1398723242`. I am trying to check this string and get the odd numbers out which in this case is `13973`.

I am facing problem on how to put this string into an array. After putting the string into an array I know that I have to loop through the array, something like this:

```
foreach($array as $value){
    if($value % 2 !== 0){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

So can any body please help on the first part on "How to put the above string into an array so I can evaluate each digit in the above loop?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split your string into an array. Then you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter the even numbers out. e.g.

```
<?php

    $str = "1398723242";
    $filtered = array_filter(str_split($str), function($v){
        return $v & 1;
    });
    echo implode("", $filtered);

?>
```

output:

```
13973
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is your function (mixed with [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php))

```
$array  = array_map('intval', str_split($number));
foreach($array as $value){
    if($value % 2 !== 0){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_split()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

```
$string = "1398723242";
$array = str_split($string);
foreach($array as $value){
    if($value % 2 !== 0){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know if the string is an array of chars. so you can just iterate it :

```
<?php
$string = "1398723242";
for($i=0; $i < strlen($string); ++$i){
    if($string[$i]=='....'){
       $string[$i] = ''; // Just replace the index like this
    }  
}
?>
```

Comment: the string is coming by POST method from an input field but I just gave a string as a sample to learn how to put the string into an array. The problem is solved now, thank you anyways.

Comment: Its not count($string) it should be *strlen($string)*

Answer (score 1):

if you want string as result, don't convert to array

```
$str = "1398723242";
echo preg_replace('/0|2|4|6|8/','', $str); //13973
```

Or, more faster

```
echo str_replace(array(0,2,4,6,8),'', $str); //13973
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str    =   '1398723242';

$strlen = strlen($str);// Get length of thr string
$newstr;
for($i=0;$i<$strlen;$i++){ // apply loop to get individual character
    if($str[$i]%2==1){ // check for odd numbers and get into a string
        $newstr .=  $str[$i]; 
    }
}
echo $newstr;
```